# Interrupt an arbitrary wait operation

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, wait

In **Boost.Thread**, we have [boost::thread::interrupt](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.interruption). However, its usage is very limited. In particular, it only applies to the wait operations as listed [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.interruption.predefined_interruption_points). So, for example, a common `mutex::lock` operation cannot be interrupted using this method. Does Boost support no full-range interruption capabilities, and there is no way to interrupt a `mutex::lock` operation? I know that, in Windows API, any wait operation can be easily interrupted using the [alertable wait functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#alertablewaitfunctions).

Comment: Short answer is no, but the longer answer is that it's already covered since the condition_variable::wait is interruptible. It would not be logical to make a mutex::lock interruptible since mutexes are there to guard extremely short-duration mutual exclusion of resources. If you're going to hold a resource for a long time it makes more sense to alert a condition variable when the operation is done.

Comment: Those windows alerts are clearly not 'any wait' -- they are waiting in an alertable manner.  C++11 lacks 'multiple wait' abilities in general.  It is a first pass.

Comment: A multiple-wait can be built from a condition_variable whose predicate tests a number of conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that `boost::thread::interrupt` is limited, and in fact was not promoted to `std::thread` in C++11 at all. The recommendation is to use a condition variable.